# Separate disconnected geometry with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is it possible to separate geometry, that is not connected, with geometry nodes, similar to `Separate -> By Loose Parts` in `Edit Mode`?

*Edit:* Since I've been too vague with my intention during my initial question here is my concrete problem:

I have a mesh consisting of disconnected diagonal edge loops (created from `Multiresolution` modified sculpt, manipulated with `Geometry Nodes`; see image). Now I want to use the vertices in these loops as points to position instances of another mesh. However both the loops themselves as well as the vetices within the loops are way too dense and thus I would like to "unsubdivide" them.

[image: High density mesh consisting of disconnected "strains"]

My plan was to separate out each loop and delete some of them as well as dissolving a portion of the vertices within each loop by index.

However the "separation" part gives me some trouble.

I hope this makes my intent a bit more clear!

Comment: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/83G5/?sorting=hot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't separate objects using geometry nodes, because it is a modifier, and modifiers can't create new objects, they can only modify the existing one.

There is a *mesh island* node, that allows to identify the separate parts of the mesh, so that you can use information to modify or delete separate mesh islands:

[image]

Update.

From your description, I believe that you want to do something like this:

[image]

Is that's right?

Comment: before another "knowitall" steals your answer....maybe it would be better to use a separate geometry node?

Comment: Don't know. It would be better if the answer had more information about what they try to achieve. But at least I have answered correctly. Good question is the half of the answer.

Comment: you are right. But he writes about "separate geometry" - not about giving separate materials.

Comment: But what does it mean separate in this context? Breaking into separate objects? Making separate instances? Apply different nodes on different parts? I've shown the node and added a minimal example how it works.

Comment: I think the answer is that it is not possible, because it's not possible to create several objects from an object with a geometry nodes modifier. (Separate > By loose parts)

Comment: Nice point, @Gorgious I've added it to post

Comment: @Crantisz I apologize for the confusion, I hope my edit helps.

Comment: @TheBeautifulOrc I've updated the post

Comment: @Crantisz Yep, that's exactly what I meant, however the second part is still missing. Do you know how I would go about deleting every n-th vertex within these separate "isles"?

Comment: quellenform has already posted a nice suggestion for this

Comment: @TheBeautifulOrc I do not understand this. Is this now about edges, faces, curves, or what question should be answered here !? ;-)

Comment: @quellenform it's complicated

Comment: @Crantisz ....Yes, looks like it :D

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of here with *Geometry Nodes* is to play about converting edges to curves.

[image]

If you have separated edges, then this is helpful.

Unfortunately, you didn't provide a blend file, so in this example I used a dummy that I created from a *UV sphere*.

You can then convert them to curves with `Mesh to Curve`.

These curves (segments) get their own index, which you can use to filter some out with the math node `Modulo`.

The remaining curves can be easily converted into curves with a lower resolution using `Resample Curve`.

[image]